# tftp logging to a separate file

Tags: logging, tftp, xinetd

I would like to log all TFTP server logging messages (and only those) to a separate log file. I'm using xinetd (extended Internet daemon) in Linux to provide a TFTP server. I tried adding

```
log_type                = SYSLOG local1
```

to /etc/xinetd.d/tftp and

```
local1.*                  /var/log/tftpd.log
```

to /etc/rsyslog.conf

but I only START and EXIT messages, such as

```
Jul 24 13:59:30 sail-staging xinetd[1364]: START: tftp pid=17955 from=x.x.x.x
Jul 24 14:17:03 sail-staging xinetd[1364]: EXIT: tftp status=0 pid=17955 duration=1053(sec)
```

Other log messages such as RRQ (which mentions the downloaded file) are still logged only to /var/log/messages.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In /etc/xinetd.d/tftp, instead of setting log_type to SYSLOG, you can set it to FILE:

```
log_type                = FILE <path_to_log_file>
```

This will normally log everything in the file whose path you specified.

(`man xinetd.conf` for more info)